# How to select which network interface to use in a ESP32

Tags: wifi, ethernet, esp32, lwip, esp-idf

I'm currently using a Esp32 which presents, in addition to wifi, an ethernet interface.
I'm using the esp-idf v3.3 with FreeRTOS.

To use it I included the "esp_eth.h" library (https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/release-v3.1/api-reference/ethernet/esp_eth.html#api-reference-phy-lan8720).

I'd like to use both Wifi and ethernet interfaces basing on what I want to do but selecting which one to use, is there a way?

The practical use is to receive a command through the ethernet interface (for example a site to ping), ping the server through the wifi interface and answer back to the ethernet interface the ping result. 
How can I select which interface to use (i dont want that the ping is made through the ethernet or that the response go through the wifi).

@edit: i found the method netif_set_default(struct netif *  netif), but i dont know if it is the best way to select the interface to use for the specific action(i should swap from one interface to another)

Answer (score 0):

Just get the IP of the Ethernet interface, then bind a socket to that IP address.

```
    struct in_addr iaddr = {0};
#if USE_ANY_IF
    // Bind the socket to any address
    iaddr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
#else
    // bind only to the Ethernet interface
    tcpip_adapter_ip_info_t ip_info = {0};
    tcpip_adapter_get_ip_info(TCPIP_ADAPTER_IF_ETH, &ip_info);
    inet_addr_from_ip4addr(&iaddr, &ip_info.ip);
#endif
```

Then use it to bind a socket, for example:

```
static int create_multicast_ipv4_socket(struct in_addr bind_iaddr)
{
    struct sockaddr_in saddr = {0};
    int sock = -1;
    int err = 0;
    char addrbuf[32] = {0};

    sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);
    if (sock < 0)
    {
        ESP_LOGE(V4TAG, "Failed to create socket. Error %d", errno);
        return -1;
    }

    saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = bind_iaddr.s_addr; // what interface IP to bind to.  Can be htonl(INADDR_ANY)
    saddr.sin_family = PF_INET;
    saddr.sin_port = htons(UDP_PORT);

    inet_ntoa_r(saddr.sin_addr.s_addr, addrbuf, sizeof(addrbuf) - 1);
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Binding to interface %s...", addrbuf);
    err = bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    if (err < 0)
    {
        ESP_LOGE(V4TAG, "Failed to bind socket. Error %d", errno);
        goto err;
    }

    // Assign multicast TTL (set separately from normal interface TTL)
    uint8_t ttl = MULTICAST_TTL;
    setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_TTL, &ttl, sizeof(uint8_t));
    if (err < 0)
    {
        ESP_LOGE(V4TAG, "Failed to set IP_MULTICAST_TTL. Error %d", errno);
        goto err;
    }

    // All set, socket is configured for sending
    return sock;

err:
    close(sock);
    return -1;
}
```